# Hearts game - Finding the Highest Value Card of the Same Suit

Tags: java

I am trying to program the game of Hearts, but am stuck on one step.

I have four card objects c1, c2, c3, c4 of random values and suits in a trickpile.

Structured : Card(int Suit, int Value);

I'm trying to find the highest Value card of the SAME suit as c1, in other words.

The person who put down the highest card that has the same suit as card c1, i.e. Spades, Hearts, Clubs, Diamonds, wins the pile of those four cards.

The person that put down the c1 card can still win the pile if they have the highest value card since it has the same suit as the original (it being the original).

I have methods already coded for returning the suit and value of the cards
 i.e. getSuit() & getValue().

Is there an easy way to do this? I can only imagine lots of nested if conditions to attain this.

Comment: Your description of the game rules are hard to understand.

Comment: What if there isn't a card in the same suit as `c1`?

Comment: im also a bit confused. What are you trying to do and not succeeding?

Comment: @Andy Turner, then player that put down c1 wins the pile.

Comment: @Vucko - I'm trying to have a simplified way to compare the suit and values of the cards as compared to card c1. However, I can only think of having many, many if conditions to do this.

Comment: Are `c1..c4` in separate variables, or are they in an array or list? (If they are separate variables, put them in an array or list)

Comment: Well what is the problem? Compare 2 cards for the same suit, if they're the same proceed to compare their values. If not, move on to the next card.

Comment: The more interesting aspect you have not indicated is how do you get the player who played a card? Or are you only interested in calculating the _highest value of same suite as c1_?

Comment: Well - you save the last putDown card. Then go through all the other (i guess these are _your_ cards). I am sure you know how to find the max value. Just include that it has to have the same suit as the last saved one

Comment: @AndyTurner They're currently separate variables, however, I can put them into an arrayList.

Comment: I'm thinking you start with `for (Card c : cards) if (c.getSuit().equals(cards.get(0).getSuit()))... `

Comment: @rpy I'm only trying to find the highest value card.

Answer (score 0):

```
     Hand temphand = new Hand();
     Card highCard;
     highCard = temphand.getCard(0);
     for(int i = 0; i < temphand.getCardCount(); i++)
     {
        if(c1.getSuit() == temphand.getCard(i).getSuit())
        {
           if(highCard.getValue() < temphand.getCard(i).getValue())
           {
              highCard = temphand.getCard(i);
           }
        }
     }
```